# One vs. multiple entry points in web apps

Tags: php, architecture, entry-point

I'm working on a major refactoring of a web application.

It currently consists of some common scripts included from all pages (common, functions, header, footer...), plus entry points for all kinds of actions (login.php, viewthis.php, viewthat.php).

Now I'm thinking of introducing a front controller and using some kind of model architecture instead.

I'd like to know:
What are the pros and cons of both architectures? Any special benefits? What should be used in general (if any)?

Comment: I think you need to go into a little more detail about what your plan is before anyone can tell you if it's a good idea or not.

Comment: Not sure. What exactly isn't clear? I'm asking because I am not sure yet. ;)

Comment: What are pros and cons of both architectures? Any special benefits? Well, that depends on what you want. There are always going to be pros and cons. But, what do you actually want. For instance, if your website is slow, you can work on it to improve performance. If its fine, why bother changing architecture at all? So, what problems are you facing with the current architecture?

Comment: Ah, okay. There are no problems actually, but front controller seems to be fairly widespread today. And I'm thinking why? Also, I know of some of the benefits (easier access control etc.), but I'm not sure how the weigh against possible downsides. The software is everything but slow. We're just trying to modernize it and this was one of the things I had on my list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend a controller. You'll gain in centralized validation of in-data, easier adaptation for mod_rewrite etc.

Can't see any real point of the other technique. It's just old.

regards,

/t